# Tabs images stretched until browser resized

Tags: javascript, wordpress, tabs

Using Wordpress Divi theme. I have a custom code block to create some tabs for tabbed content.

The tabs mostly work fine, but the image galleries in the tabs are stretched until the browser is resized a little. It seems like some javascript isn't kicking in or something...? Go here and click on a tab to see what I mean:

Here are the tabs:

```js
 function openCategory(evt, categoryName) {
    // Declare all variables
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;

    // Get all elements with class="tabcontent" and hide them
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }

    // Get all elements with class="tablinks" and remove the class "active"
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }

    // Show the current tab, and add an "active" class to the link that opened the tab
    document.getElementById(categoryName).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
```

```css
/* Style the list */
ul.tab {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

/* Float the list items side by side */
ul.tab li {float: left;}

/* Style the links inside the list items */
ul.tab li a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: 0.3s;
    font-size: 17px;
}

/* Change background color of links on hover */
ul.tab li a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

/* Create an active/current tablink class */
ul.tab li a:focus, .active {background-color: #ccc;}

/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
    display: none;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-top: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="tab">
  <li><a href="#" class="tablinks" onclick="openCategory(event, 'Sleek')">Sleek</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="tablinks" onclick="openCategory(event, 'Soft')">Soft</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="tablinks" onclick="openCategory(event, 'Contemporary')">Contemporary</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="tablinks" onclick="openCategory(event, 'Traditional')">Traditional</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="Sleek" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Sleek</h3>
  <p>[showmodule id="26937"]</p>
</div>

<div id="Soft" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Soft</h3>
  <p>[showmodule id="26935"]</p> 
</div>

<div id="Contemporary" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Contemporary</h3>
  <p>[showmodule id="#"]</p>
</div>

<div id="Traditional" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Traditional</h3>
  <p>[showmodule id="#"]</p>
</div>
```

You can see the behaviour here: http://devstone.05creative.com/portfolio-test
Click on one of the first 2 tabs, then resize the browser a little.

Help!

Thanks

Comment: Thank you. Is this okay now?

Comment: Can anyone help please?